# ng-disabled not disabiling html element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not understanding why ng-disabled not working from a scope value. I have even printed the value to html view to ensure that what is coming from the scope is exactly same as expected.

here are snippets:

```
$scope.disableBtn = "invalid";
alert($scope.disableBtn); //alerts invalid
```

html view:

```
<a ng-disabled="disableBtn === 'invalid'" >
    <i  ng-click="goBack()" class="left chevron icon"></i>
    Back
</a>
```

this also prints invalid

```
<p> print test value {{disableBtn}} </p>
```

please what could be wrong? as this is weird to me

Comment: Also trying to access by boolean may that would work with your case instead of invalid

Comment: I want to disable the view when test is equal to invalid

Comment: can you post an answer

Comment: ng-disabled="variable1==true" 
 set you variable value to true or false and then try it.

Comment: @pawansgi92 did not work

Comment: did you try according to the below answer of my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-class` instead. Create a class

```
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

And then,

```
<a ng-class="{{'disabled' : disableBtn === 'invalid'}}">
    <i  ng-click="goBack()" class="left chevron icon" ></i>
    Back
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-disabled="variable1==true" 
 set you variable value to true or false and then try it.

also try the below code with adding span in it just like i added in the code

```
<span ng-disabled="disableBtn === 'invalid'">
    <a>
    <i  ng-click="goBack()" class="left chevron icon"></i>
    Back
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: you can try by above one may be it works with you.

Comment: this answer did not work for me